# Unable to get access token from Paypal sdk. Got an Exception says “Authentication needed”

Tags: ios, paypal, oauth

I am using PayPal SDK for adaptive payment...I get PayPal Payment Success message in

```
 - (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully;    send to server for verification and fulfillment
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server

    NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and    fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);

    payId=[[completedPayment.confirmation objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"id"];

    [self callForAccessToken];  ///////calll webservice to get access token
}

- (void)callForAccessToken {
    NSString *shippingURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *shippingRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:shippingURL]];
    [shippingRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    shippingRequest.tag=1010;
    [shippingRequest setPostValue:@"application/json" forKey:@"Accept"];
    [shippingRequest setPostValue:@"en_US" forKey:@"Accept-Language"];
    NSString *clientIDSecret=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"kClientID:kClientsecret"];
    [shippingRequest setPostValue:clientIDSecret forKey:@"clientId:secret"];
    [shippingRequest setPostValue:@"client_credentials" forKey:@"grant_type"];
    [shippingRequest setDelegate:self];
    [shippingRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinishedLocation:)];
    [shippingRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailLocation:)];
    [shippingRequest startAsynchronous];       
}

- (void)uploadFinishedLocation:(ASIHTTPRequest *)requestObj {
    NSString *response = [requestObj responseString];
    NSLog(@"\n\nReq tag %ld Response string in Payment Didload %@\n\n",(long)requestObj.tag,response);       
}

- (void)uploadFailLocation:(ASIHTTPRequest *)requestObj {
    NSLog(@"%@",requestObj.error.description);
}
```

When I execute code `uploadFailLocation` is called...
And I get error:

> " Authentication needed "

I got reference to pass all data in post form in key-valuse combination by this link.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token

So have I pass client id and secredt right way or something is missing.......
Or is there any other way to do this things.....

Answer (score 1):

The generating of an access token is a server to server call and is not done from your App itself.  Also, when doing so, the client ID and secret are sent in the headers and not just posted as key>value.  The steps to verify a mobile payment can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).

Comment: I don't how how to make correct url from these curl syntex..will you please help me..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request.  You aren't going to make a URL to simply redirect/post to.  You send the information back to your server and use a server side script to do the payment verification.